# React Native: How to inline a toggle switch with a textInput?

Tags: react-native, argon

This is what I have done so far:

[image]

I want the text input to extent until reaches end of box.

Here's my code:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
     <Switch style={styles.switch}
             trackColor={{true: "#36d79a", false: 'grey'}}
             thumbColor={{true: "#36d79a", false: 'grey'}}
     />
    <Input right placeholder="Type your custom question here." iconContent= 
   {<Block />} 
     />
</View>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fill space along the main axis of flexboxes, apply the `flex` property with a number value to flex children. The number specifies the proportions of how the available space is distributed among the flex children. See the docs on [flexbox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex) for details.

In your case, you would specify `flex: 1` only for the `<Input />` meaning that this component alone is allowed to fill the rest of the space. I've created this [React Native & MUI Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-flexbox-e5bzcu?file=/src/App.js) to demonstrate it.

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
     <Switch style={styles.switch}
             trackColor={{true: "#36d79a", false: 'grey'}}
             thumbColor={{true: "#36d79a", false: 'grey'}}
     />
    <Input style={{ flex: 1 }} right placeholder="Type your custom question here." iconContent= 
   {<Block />} 
     />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to your main View.
Alternatively, you can always use placeholder views:
`<View style={{ flex: 1 }}`. You would put that placeholder between the Switch and the Input.

Comment: Edited my description and the image. @Maximilian

Comment: There you go, that should work.